# Operator Overloading ( = )

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm just a beginner in the C++ language and I have some questions on this piece of code. I am trying to overload some operators.

```
string& operator = (char R) { string T = R ; *this = T; return *this; }
```

**First Question:** Why I need to overload the equal operator while the constructor can do the job? 
**Second Question:**  (Not Related) What does `(char R)` means?

Comment: All about operator overloading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: There is no Operator overloading in C!

Comment: post the class definition, is it T a template?

Comment: C is not equal to C++. Fixed that for you.

Comment: it is string T (edited it).. about the C thing.. I know.. It just didn't get removed.. it stuck there dunno why, sorry about that and thanks for the edit :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **First Question**: Why I need to overload the equal operator while the constructor can do the job?

The constructor is designed to "construct" an object ... while there is something called a copy-constructor, it is not designed to actually copy an already existing object into another already existing object of the same (or convertable) type ... that is the job of the `operator=`.  Also you are not "overloading" the `operator=` method, but rather creating a user-defined version of the method to be used instead of the default compiler-created method for the object type which would simply brute-force copy the bits of the memory footprint of one object into another ... if your object is managing it's own pointers, etc., such a brute-force copy can be a very bad thing as pointer ownership becomes ambiguous, etc.

Comment: Got the point.. I forgot that the constructor is only called once.. so because of that we use those user-defined versions for farther edit.. right?

Comment: Right, after the constructor is called and the object instance exists, then the assignment operator is used for copies.  Keep in mind the ["Rule of Three"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) though ... if you actually need a user-defined assignment operator, then you probably also need a user-defined copy-constructor and destructor for your class since you are most likely managing resources the default compiler versions of those methods will fail to handle correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`(char R)` is the right-side argument of the operator (here `=`)

You want to do that so you can set a value *after* initialization

```
//constructor
Foo a('f')
//copy constructor
Foo b = Foo('p');
// operator=
b = 'g';
```

Answer (score 0):

`(char R)` is the argument to the operator just like you have an argument to a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading in C++ . One of best version here.

http://msumca2012.blogspot.in/2013/03/oop-41-operator-overloading-in-c.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.